# Does function parameter names has a place in memory in C?

Tags: c, function, memory, parameters

I dont think function parameter names are treated like variables and they doesnt get stored in memory. But I dont get how we can use these parameters in functions as variables if they dont have any place in memory. Can anyone explain me whats going on with function parameters and if they have place or not in memory

Comment: All you claim is wrong. A function parameter is the same as a local variable that has been initialized by the caller of the function. A function parameter can be in memory or in a CPU register exactly as a local variable.

Comment: You can take the address of a parameter with the `&` operator (as long as it has not been declared with the `register` storage class), and access it indirectly via a pointer, just like you can with variables. That is true even if the parameter values are passed in registers during the function call. So really, they behave just like local variables inside the function, except that parameters of array types are changed to pointer types.

Comment: Regardless of how parameter values are passed to parameters in function calls, it's really up to the compiler where it stores the parameter inside the function, and it is free to move it around between registers and memory or to discard it when no longer required.

Answer (score 4):

All variables are either allocated somewhere or optimized away in case the compiler found them unnecessary. Function parameters are variables and are almost certainly stored either in a CPU register or on the stack, if they are used by the program.

The only time when they might not get allocated is when the function is *inlined* - when the whole function call is optimized away and the function code is instead injected in the caller-side machine code. In such cases the original variables used by the caller might be used instead.

Function parameter *names* however are not stored anywhere in the final executable, just like any other identifier isn't stored there either. Names of variables, functions etc only exist in the source code, for the benefit of the programmer alone.

Answer (score 2):

Although your title asks about “function parameter names,” it appears your question is about function parameters, which are different.

Commonly, arguments are passed to functions by putting them in processor registers or on the hardware stack. Each computing platform has some specification of which arguments should be passed where. For example, the first few small arguments (such as `int` values) may be passed in certain processor registers, while more or larger arguments may be put on the stack.

To the called function, these are parameters. The called function uses them from the processor registers or the stack.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm writing this answer assuming you know what the stack and CPU registers are. If you don't, I'd suggest you look them up before seeing this answer.*

> I dont think function parameter names are treated like variables and they doesnt get stored in memory.

At the assembly level, function parameter *names* don't really exist. But for function parameters, it depends on the assembly generated based on the compiler's level of optimization. Consider this simple function:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Using [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), I checked the generated disassembly of x64 GCC 10.2. On `-O0`, it looks like this:

```
foo:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        add     eax, edx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

These two lines:

```
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
```

interestingly show that the arguments are passed to `edi` and `esi` for `a` and `b` respectively, and then moved into the stack, presumably in case the registers need to be used elsewhere in the function. The rest of the function uses the space in the stack as opposed to the registers:

```
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
add     eax, edx
```

(In case you didn't know, `eax`/`rax` generally holds the value for functions and `edx` in this case just serves as a general-purpose register, so these three lines are besaically `eax = a; edx = b; eax += edx`).

Ok, so that makes sense. The arguments are passed to registers and copied to the stack, where they are used for the rest of the function. What about `-O1`?

```
foo:
        lea     eax, [rdi+rsi]
        ret
```

Now that is a lot shorter. Here, `eax` gets the value of `rdi + rsi` and the function ends. All the copying to the stack is completely skipped and the registers are used directly. So yes, in this case, the memory is never used.

### EDIT

After writing this answer, I went and checked the generated assembly with the `-m32` option and noticed that arguments were always pushed to the stack before the function was called. Assembly generated from `-O0` looks like this:

```
foo:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
        add     eax, edx
        pop     ebp
        ret
```

Here, since the arguments are passed to the stack before the function is called, they don't have be copied from the registers to the stack (because they're already there). So the function is shorter, and amount of registers used is reduced. However, on higher levels of optimization, the function ends up becoming longer because of this:

```
foo:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
        ret
```

So with `-m32` set, parameters are *always* placed in memory.